# Intelij idea caret adds visual spaces in line

Tags: intellij-idea

guys how can I disable this feature?

IntelliJ IDEA 2016.3.4 / 
Build #IU-163.12024.16, built on January 31, 2017 / 
Mac OS 10.12.3 / 
Scheme: Base16 Ocean Dark /
Font: Source Code Pro / 
There are no any installed plug-ins /
JRE: 1.8.0_112-release-408-b6 x86_64 / 
JVM: OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM

[Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qZk1g.png)

GIF - https://gyazo.com/30c436a10427e1ac618074e02a1dfd88

Comment: IDE/Java/OS versions? Third-party plug-ins installed? Any font customizations in IDE settings?

Comment: IntelliJ IDEA 2016.3.4 / Mac OS 10.12.3 / Scheme: Base16 Ocean Dark / without plug-ins /
Build #IU-163.12024.16, built on January 31, 2017
JRE: 1.8.0_112-release-408-b6 x86_64
JVM: OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM by JetBrains s.r.o

Comment: Does it happen with the default scheme and font settings?

Comment: With the default scheme it's all okay, and with "Base16 Ocean Dark" has a problem.

Comment: Where did you get the theme? Who is the vendor? You can either try a different font or report a bug to the theme maintainer.

Comment: http://color-themes.com/ - from here.. The problem with font size!! Thanks a lot!!

Answer (score 1):

The issue is specific to **Base16 Ocean Dark** custom color scheme from https://github.com/sdvoynikov/color-themes

It's either caused by the Menlo font used by the scheme or by some other theme setting which may not work properly in the recent IDE versions.

The solution is to try a different scheme or try some other font or change the font size.